# Finding the bounds (if they exist) and the maximum and minimum of the group

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to find the supremum and  infimum of a group $C={\{\frac pq| p \in Z , 1 \le q \in N, {p^2}\le 2 {q^2}\}}$

I started by using the ${p^2} \le 2{q^2}$ and got to  $-\sqrt2 \le \frac pq \le \sqrt2$

but now I'm trying to prove that $\sqrt2$ is the supremum, I know I need to assume there's an m $\lt$ $\sqrt2$ where m $\gt$ $\frac pq$ but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Nitpick:  You should use the word "set" and not the word "group".  "group" has a specific meaning in mathematics that does not apply here.

Comment: Hint if $\frac pq < m < \sqrt 2$ then there is an $h>0$ where $m = \frac pq + h$.  We need 1) $m^2 = (\frac pq + h)^2 = (\frac pq)^2 + 2h\frac pq + h^2 < 2$ and 2) $h$ is rational.  Try to find possible values for $h$.  Hint: It's an inequality so it doesn't have to be exact.  Hint:  If we fit $h < 1$ we have $h^2 < h$ and it'd be enough to find $h$ where $(\frac pq)^2 + 2h\frac pq + h^2< (\frac pq)^2 + 2h\frac pq + h < 2$.

Comment: The big problem with this question is we really have not idea what level it is and what we are allowed to assume is known.  You mention $\sqrt 2$ but do you even know that such a concept even exists?  I sort of think this exercise is a preliminary to prove it does. ... but then on the other hand if we *don't* know such a number exist we can't actually state a value for the supremum.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your second inequality, you mean $-\sqrt{2}\leq \frac{p}{q}\leq \sqrt{2}$, but then it is correct.

A nice way to continue the proof is using Archimedean property: assume you have some $m$ such that $\frac{p}{q}<m<\sqrt{2}$ for all $\frac{p}{q}\in C$. By the Archimedean property, there exists some fraction $\frac{k}{n}$ satisfying $m<\frac{k}{n}<\sqrt{2}$. Now, what can you say about that fraction, and how is it a contradiction?

Same tactic will work for the infimum.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $\sqrt 2$ is the supremum, one has to show that for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ such that
$$ \sqrt2-\varepsilon<\frac pq<\sqrt 2 $$
which is true since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. You can use the same argument for $-\sqrt2$.